# JS handler for radio toggle only on user click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events, jquery-events

I am trying to write a JS handler for radio toggle but I want to handle the radio toggle only when it happens via user click. So basically I am looking to handle events which are an intersection of `change` and `click` events.

The original handler :

```
$(document).delegate(".some-class input[type='radio']", "change", function(event) {
}
```

also gets triggered when the radio button is set to 'checked' either in JS on in HTMl template.
If I am using only a `click` event :

```
$(document).delegate(".some-class input[type='radio']", "click", function(event) {
}
```

then the handler gets triggered also when user clicks on an already selected radio button, naturally.

I am looking for a way to somehow detect an even sort of `['click' && 'change']`. Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Comment: don't do this, it breaks accessibility - controls should be operable with the keyboard

Comment: @WillJenkins Need this to fix a bug which is causing implicit triggers of the 'change' handler on page load.

Comment: ok, so you have a problem but this isn't the way to fix it